# Get configs from background page to content script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get some user configs from the background page of my chrome extension to the content script (or popup) but I'm having some problems, I think the problem is that chrome.storage.sync.get is async, I tried using callbacks but I also read that callbacks can't return the value so I have no idea how to solve this.

Here's kinda how the code looks:

**popup.js:**

```
(function() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    message: "loadconfig"
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'success') {
      console.log(response);
    } else {
      console.log(response.except);
    }
  });
})();
```

**background.js**

```
(function() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.message) {
      case "loadconfig":
        sendResponse(loadStuff());
        break;
      default:
        sendResponse({
          reply: null
        });
        break;
    }
  });
  function loadStuff() {
    var to_return_configs = {
      blocked_characters: '',
      good_post: ''
    };
    var function_status = 'failed';
    var exception = '';
    var blocked_characters_parsed, good_post_parsed;

    try {
      var to_get = ["blocked_characters_saved", "good_post_saved"];
      chrome.storage.sync.get(to_get, function(result) {
        to_get.forEach(function(got) {
          if (got === "good_post_saved") {
            to_return_configs.good_post = result[got];
          }
          if (got === "blocked_characters_saved") {
            to_return_configs.blocked_characters = result[got];
          }
        });
      });
      exception = '';
      function_status = 'success';
    } catch (err) {
      exception = String(err);
      function_status = 'failed';
    }
    var to_return = {
      status: function_status,
      configs: to_return_configs,
      except: (exception)
    };
    return to_return;
  }
})();
```

The problem here is that when I'm looking at the popup.js console, "blocked_characters" and "good_post" are both empty.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need Message API for communication between Popup and Background. Popup in chrome extension can directly call methods of Background .

You can do something like [this](https://github.com/blunderboy/requestly/blob/da994ef92b07baee9d129ec70a3748918a06b9a8/src/pages/js/app.js#L2)

```
BG = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
```

And then you can call `BG.loadStuff()` in your popup js.

From within loadStuff, you can pass a callback which can return data to you. So it should look like

```
BG.loadStuff(function(items) {
  console.log(items);
});
```

background.js

```
function loadStuff(cb) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(superObj) {
    cb.call(null, superObj);
  });
}
```

For more understanding, read these

1. http://blog.papersapp.com/chrome-development-parent-and-child-windows/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276475/816213
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378016/816213

Answer (score 0):

`sendResponse(function)` becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until `sendResponse` is called). See the reference: [onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).

Because `sendResponse` is called asynchronously in `chrome.storage.sync.get`'s callback, you need to return true from the `onMessage` listener to prevent the function from being invalidated. Code similar is Like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message === 'loadconfig') {
        sendResponse(loadStuff());
        return true;
       }
      return false;
    });
```