# Struggling with Chrome Extension architecture

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extension development, and I'm a bit struggling with the architecture to put in place. 
I would like to develop an extension (browser_action), that, when the button is clicked, opens a window where information will be populated from the WebTraffic. 
I figured out I could use the WebRequest API to get info about the traffic.

I could create a popup window, but it's displayed only when I click on the extension button, and hides as soon as I click somewhere else

I tried creating a background window, but it does not show up.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me with the initial setup of my application.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need both.

Take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch), or maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28998352/934239).

The lifetime of the popup is indeed equal to how long it stays on screen. It's the UI part, but putting logic there is usually bad.

A background page is permanently there but invisible. It's typically the "brain" of an extension, taking care of heavy lifting and routing messages to other parts.

In short:

1. You need a background script to collect `webRequest` information for you in some format.
2. You need a popup page to show it. Keep in mind it's not guaranteed to be present at a given time and can close at any time.
3. It's probably best to use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to request the information from the background page. If you need real-time updates, you can use long-lived connections.

   In your case you can also tightly couple the two and call [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) to directly reference stuff in it.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I reviewed the links you sent me, but it's not clear yet. The behaviour I'd like to achieve is that when the user clicks on the extension button, a browser window opens, and stays there until I close it. Then, from the popup, I should be able to start/stop data collection, and when collection is 'on', I should see the results in the output window. How could I achieve this? (basically, what I'd like to display is the cookies sent and received). Thanks a lot

Comment: You can open a tab/window with your custom html file:
`chrome.extension.getURL('somepage.html')`,
where "somepage.html" is a file in the extension directory. You can access  to the background page from this file:
`var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`
or using messaging.

Comment: actually, the popup is not necessary. As long as clicking on the icon opens up the window, it's fine. But I could find how to do it without a popup window including the js to open the main window. Thanks so much

Comment: Yeah, having a popup and having a `browserAction.onClicked` events are mutually exclusive. Glad you found a way.

Comment: Theres also chrome apis to create split windows like the debugger. Never used them thou.

Comment: @ZigMandel [citation needed]. There was an experimental sidebar API some time ago but it's effectively abandoned.

Comment: No. I mean develop another debugger tab.