# Chrome Extension: "Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my first Chrome Extension ever, as well as js not being one of my strong smoots. I have a feeling this is something pretty simple, that just slipping by me due to lack of experience in both.

I'm trying to read from storage, and place what is read (or the default) into a text field. It *appears* that it's not finding the element ID: 'orgurl' which is why it's not able to fill the field, but I may be wrong.

I'm getting the error in the title during this chunk of code (see the line marked "BUG"):

```
function restore_options() {

    // Use default value of https://o.yourdomain.com
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        oURL: 'https://o.yourdomain.com'
    }, function(items) {
        document.getElementById('orgurl').value = items.oURL; // BUG: NOT filling it into the text box
    });

}
```

(NOTE: That code is taken almost verbatim from the Chrome Developers page: https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/options)

If I add `console.log(items.oURL)` just before the line with the bug, it does show the proper info, it's just not able to add the info to the text field.

I'm calling it within the same js file (options.js) as this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
```

Since Chrome extensions are pretty intertwined, I'll also add all of the relevant content of the extension, in hopes it might help.

**Manifest**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "O Viewer",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/images/icon16.png",
    "32": "assets/images/icon32.png",
    "48": "assets/images/icon48.png",
    "128": "assets/images/icon128.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["assets/js/options.js", "assets/js/popup.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "pages/popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/images/icon16.png",
      "32": "assets/images/icon32.png",
      "48": "assets/images/icon48.png",
      "128": "assets/images/icon128.png"
    }
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["assets/js/options.js", "assets/js/popup.js"],
      "match_about_blank": false
    }
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://o.yourdomain.com; object-src 'self'",

  "options_ui": {
    "chrome_style": true,
    "page": "pages/options.html",
    "open_in_tab": false
  },

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

**Options.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>O Viewer: Settings</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script href="../assets/js/options.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="options-header">
            <h1 class="logo">
                <a href="https://blah.com" id="logo-title">Options</a>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="options-content">

            <label id="orgurllabel">
                URL to your O Server:
                <span id="orgurlex">(ex. https://o.yourdomain.com)</span>
                <input id="orgurl" type="text"> 
            </label>

            <div id="save_status"></div>
            <button id="save_options">Save</button>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Is `items.oURL` defined?

Comment: Remove `assets/js/options.js` from `background` script. There is no logic using same js in background and content script. However, if part of code from `assets/js/options.js` is being used in bacground script, create a separate bg.js file for that purpose. Same comments for `assets/js/popup.js`

Comment: You are correct, the call to `getElementById` is not finding the element (it returns `null`). I suspect it's running in the background page, which does not have access to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the different scripts included in the `manifest.json` are causing some confusion when you try to hunt down your error. The comments above are correct that you should be able to remove `assets/js/options.js` and `assets/js/popup.js` from both the `background` and `content_scripts` sections in your manifest. Those can be called directly from `options.html` and `popup.html` instead. If you don't have any background and content scripts just yet, you may have to delete those entries completely to get your extension to load.

Once you have your manifest pared down, it should clear up the errors you see when you load the extension or inspect the background page and make troubleshooting simpler. In this case, it looks like your JS is working fine but you have a small typo (`<script href="../assets/js/options.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="../assets/js/options.js"></script>`) keeping it from loading on your options page.

There's a great overview of all the Chrome extension scripts and pages at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999241/2581399 that might make it easier to keep track of what's firing where.