# Inject (content_scripts) website who using Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, requirejs

I am trying to access **JS variables** on some website with my **Chrome extension**

But that website using **Require.js**

I tried with :

**Manifest.json**

```
"content_scripts": [{
   "matches":["*://*.example.com/*"],
   "js":["src/inject/inject.js"],
   "run_at":"document_end"
}]
```

**Inject.js**

```
console.log(require); // not defined
console.log(requirejs); // not defined
console.log(jQuery); // not defined

window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(require); // not defined
        console.log(requirejs); // not defined
        console.log(jQuery); // not defined
    },5000);
};
```

**Any trick ?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246133/contexts-and-methods-for-communication-between-the-browser-action-background-sc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script

Comment: @RobW So thanks , I should accept your command as an answer :D

Comment: Which of the two provides the most helpful answer to your question? Then I'll mark your question as a duplicate of that, so that others who have a similar question as you will immediately be redirected to the duplicate.

Comment: Yep do it. sorry that @RobW

Comment: No problem! Without knowing the answer you couldn't have known that the answer is already covered in depth in the other questions. Your clear question may help others in the same situation to find the answer more quickly. I think that you can vote to close the question as a duplicate of either question (because you have 3k+ rep). If you do that, then I'll also vote to close with the other question and then the question will be linked to these two other questions.